# JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7" -> Unrecognized option 7

Tags: fedora, java, wine

I am trying to install the latest version of PSIM which is a windows application. I downloaded the latest version of JAVA as well as JAVA 8 (in case it doesn't like the latest) and set the variable `export JAVA_HOME=\path`. When I run the installer using `wine` it loads and says:

```
> **Flexeraax2$aaa: Windows DLL failed to load** 
>     at Flexeraax2.af(Unknown Source) 
>     at Flexeraax2.aa(Unknown Source)
>     at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.init(Unknown Source) 
>     at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown
> Source)
>     at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
>     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

I searched the internet and the only suggestion I found was to make JAVA think it is running on windows 7. That means exporting `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7"`.

However, after running `java -version` it says that `unrecognized option 7`. I have also tried `windows 10`, `windows 11`. It cannot recognize them. I have also changed wine's config to run the installer using windows 7, but it spits out the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should work: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3245

Comment: @ChanganAuto It does, I have used it before by copying it already installed. The issue is I can't install it.

Comment: Just a guess, but try `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows\ 7"`  (or `...=Windows7"` ?